# MathNet Raise Scalar by a Matrix

Tags: c#, math, machine-learning, f#, sigmoid

I'm attempting to implement Logistic regression in .net using MathNumerics Linear Algebra libraries.  I need to implement the following equation and am unsure of how to accomplish raising e by a matrix.

1.0 ./ (1.0 + E .^ (-1 .* Z))

where Z is a matrix and E is the mathematical constant e.

So the problematic section of code is E .^ Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let sigmoid (z : Matrix<double>) : Matrix<double> =
        z.Map (fun x -> 1.0 / (1.0 + exp (0.0 - x)))
```

Comment: Of interest: [Sigmoid neurons](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#sigmoid_neurons)

Comment: Accord .NET has this kind of stuff. Also you can reach out to R with the R typeprovider. http://accord-framework.net/

Comment: @s952163 Can Accord.NET make use of the GPU?

Comment: I'm re-implementing some stuff I have in matlab with a goal to use GPUs at some point.

Comment: @Guy: This is the underlayment for my neural network implementations as well, as you hinted in the first comment :)  I'm trying to make as generic as possible.  Totally agree. I can't stand waiting for hours as a deep net trains...

Comment: @Guy: I was going to take a look at Cudafy after I get it running with MathNumerics.

Comment: @guycoder probably not but I haven't done anything in gpus.

Comment: @GuyCoder I'm assuming you do this as your day job?  You seem to be deeper than most i meet.

Comment: actually I'm starting to think this isn't right...need to think a bit first, but I'm getting poor results..

Comment: sigmoid in a binary classifier should return a scalar, in a multi-class should return a column vector of scalars

Comment: no, I think its right and my head is messed up...I'll post back in a bit.  I need to get a coffee or something