# Dot product function

Tags: .net, matrix, f#

I write a dot product function that takes 2 lists:

```
let inline dot a b =
    List.zip a b
    |> List.map (fun (a, b) -> a * b)
    |> List.reduce (+)
```

Is there a better way to calculate dot product without using `List.zip`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One shorter way would be to use `List.map2`:

```
let inline dot a b = List.map2 (*) a b |> List.sum
```

Another would be to use `List.fold2`:

```
let inline dot a b = List.fold2 (fun state x y -> state + x * y) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero a b
```

Comment: The `inline` in the second function will not help since the `0` forces it to have return type `int`.

Comment: If the `inline` is to make the function generalizable, using `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` instead of `0` would work. If it's just to tell the compiler "don't generate a function call here", then it's fine as-is.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same need for doing neural networks with F# with matrixes, but you could probably use Vectors.

I used [MathNet Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) which has among many other functions [dot product](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseVector.htm#DotProduct).

Make sure you get both the [core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/) and the [F# extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics.FSharp/).

If you are doing neural networks and will use MathNet Numerics with Matrices then you will probably want the [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)

[MathNet Raise Scalar by a Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37594281/1243762)

Here is a backpropagation [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992809/1243762) related to neural networks using MathNet Numerics matrix in F#.

Answer (score 3):

Among the three proposed ones, I believe the one using `List.fold2` is the fastest:

```
let inline dot1 a b =
    List.zip a b
    |> List.map (fun (a, b) -> a * b)
    |> List.reduce (+)

let inline dot2 a b = List.map2 (*) a b |> List.sum

// Modified with 0.0 instead of 0 and no 'inline'
let dot3 a b = List.fold2 (fun state x y -> state + x * y) 0.0 a b

let xs = [0.0..1000000.0]

> dot1 xs xs;;
Real: 00:00:00.242,

> dot2 xs xs;;
Real: 00:00:00.070

> dot3 xs xs;;
Real: 00:00:00.003
```

Zipping the two lists is probably quite expensive. The `map2-sum` solution is faster but iterates twice through the list. The `fold2` solution only goes once through the list.

Comment: Why did you use `0.0` and not `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` to make `dot3` a generic function? I beilive not forcing generics could make functions evaluate faster, right?

Comment: @MiP - I am not sure. I tried again with `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` instead of `0.0` and the speed did not change appreciably.